# How to get id from view binding android for getting radio button text value

Tags: android, kotlin, android-viewbinding

I have bottom sheet in a page that contains radio button. I'm using view binding to get the layout and here is the code

```
        bindingfilter = DataBindingUtil.inflate(layoutInflater, R.layout.item_sheet_switching_filter, null, false)
        bindingfilter!!.btConfirm.setOnClickListener {
        val intSelectButton: Int = bindingfilter!!.rgType.checkedRadioButtonId
        radioButton = findViewById(intSelectButton)}
        val txt : String? = radioButton.text
```

the problem is NullPointerException in `findViewById(intSelectButton)` I know that is because I tried to find that id, not in the right layout, I want to get that from bindingFilter. but How?

Comment: Can you add your layout file?

Comment: Whats the point of using `DataBinding` if you are still using `findViewById` ? That defeat the whole purpose . Assign an Id to your radio Button u will get one back

Comment: @ADM I see and I've already assign ids to those radio buttons, but I can't find any function to get the selected radio button in the radio group or maybe don't know yet.  Do you know how to get that sir?

Comment: You'll get it by `bindingfilter!!.rgType.findViewById()` . not sure thought . code is not enough to answer .

Comment: that's it !!!, thank you  @ADM